# Can i disable RDS when i installed mysql in ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using 1 ec2 instance and OS is ubuntu. I installed mysql, php in the ec2 instance.
My RDS Service charge is coming high.
I don't know if RDS service is required for me. Can i disable this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can temporarily turn off an RDS instance as of 6/1/7:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/

Keep in mind that you can only turn it off for upto 7 days and then it will turn back on by itself (and begin accruing charges again), so make sure you either delete it before the 7 days is up if you decide you don't need it, or else make sure to turn it *back* off after it turns back on.